# Newsletter banner that shows up in gmail but not in outlook

Tags: php, templates, html-email

I have a custom template for one of my newsletter templates. It looks good in all the other email clients but not in Outlook. How can I fix it?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: you have issues with an implementation post your code please in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so we can help you out.

Comment: How should I post my code?

Comment: @IsuruLiyanage you can post your code by editing your question and pasting code either inline or in a snippet.

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't always display HTML content for some strange reasons. That's why you will often find certain links not being able to be clicked in outlook because of the same very reason. You will need to provide alternative text for your banner.